# Display expanded row conditionally for antd tables

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following table:

```
  <Table
    bordered
    loading={false}
    columns={this.columns(currentUser, fields)}
    dataSource={selectedAssets}
    expandedRowRender={(rec) => <AssetsExtraInformationTable {...rec} />}
    rowKey={(record) => record.id}
    pagination={false}
  />
```

but I'm willing to display the `+` button of `expandedRowRender` only when I have data to expand.
I couldn't find something in the [API doc](https://ant.design/components/table/#API), neither in the [React component Table API](https://github.com/react-component/table#api), that allows me to do that, so I wonder if there is any hacky way to do this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you display `+` in separate column, you can define [render](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) option for that, i.e.:

```
render: (text, record, index) => record.hasExpandData ? <div>{text}</div> : null,
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, that makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting Antd version 3.11.3 you can use the [expandIcon prop](https://ant.design/components/table/#API)
Example:

```
const CustomExpandIcon = props => {
  if (!props.record.subData) return null; //nothing to expand
  if (props.expanded) {
    return (
      <a onClick={e => props.onExpand(props.record, e)}>
        <Icon type="minus" />
      </a>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <a onClick={e => props.onExpand(props.record, e)}>
        <Icon type="plus" />
      </a>
    );
  }
};
```

and then:

```
 <Table expandIcon={p => <CustomExpandIcon {...p} />} />
```